# How can I get a smooth, flicker-free GUI for an app run via Remote Desktop?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, remote-desktop, flicker

I realize there are a ton of questions floating around the internet about reducing flicker in Windows Forms applications. After copious experimentation, I found that the solution in my particular case was quite straightforward: setting the `Control.DoubleBuffered` property to true for the controls that were exhibiting flicker. I accomplished this by simply deriving from the necessary control classes (in my case, from `ListView` to `DoubleBufferedListView` and from `DataGridView` to `DoubleBufferedDataGridView`).

The primary culprit in the app I am working on is a `DataGridView` which updates many of its cells on the `Tick` event of a `Windows.Forms.Timer` object. Before enabling double buffering, the grid would flicker slightly (not too bad, but enough to be noticeable) on most updates. *After* enabling double buffering, the flicker went away.

However, I'm talking about my development machine here. Unfortunately, this app is actually run by end users via a Remote Desktop connection, which I learned from [this blog post by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/03/508694.aspx) means I should **not** use double buffering.

My question, then, is: what **should** I use? Chen suggests switching between a double buffered approach on local machines and the traditional non-double buffered approach on remote desktop connections; but in that case the end users of this app will still experience the flicker. Is this simply unavoidable?

For the record: this is **not** a simple matter of calling `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate` (already doing that on `ListBox` and `ListView` controls) or `SuspendLayout`/`ResumeLayout` (already doing that for the `DataGridView` control as well, although I don't think that's even particularly important since, as I said, I'm just updating the values in certain cells).

Maybe a flicker-free remote desktop app is simply impossible?

Comment: What does it look like without double buffering under terminal server?

Comment: @jdv: For lack of a better description, some of the cells in the `DataGridView` control occasionally appear to "flicker" or "blink" -- though nothing severe. This was also visible on a local machine, but was fixed (on the local machine) with double buffering. It's merely an annoyance which the users would prefer to have fixed if possible.

Comment: The cost of the bitmap transfer is unavoidable when you enable double-buffering.  Have they actually tried it and are actively complaining?  A 1GB network zaps those bitmaps across the wire pretty quick.  You're otherwise pretty stuck until you start considering ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

In the category "worth a try": Set the flag `AllPaintingInWmPaint` on the control, or override OnPaintBackground as suggested here: http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Craig/FlickerFreeControlDrawing.html

This would help to get the background paint closer in time to foreground paint. This will improve that chance that they will be sent simultaneously from client to server.